# Windows install (media drivers)

Tags: windows-7, drivers, ubuntu-12.04

I have been trying to install windows 7 64bit onto my Ubuntu 12.04 machine for quite awhile. I succeeded in installing the win7 64bit iso onto my usb via unetbootin-linux-494 and formating the usb into NTFS format via gparted. This created a bootable Win7 USB.

I get the following error when I try to install windows from the usb: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2755139

Does anyone know what media drivers there are and how I can get them? If it matters, I do not think that my CD/DVD drive is working which is why I am using a USB to install Windows.

Someone told me that it may be because the Windows installation wasn't able to read the drivers from the USB, but i'm not quite sure if that is the issue. If anyone has advice on this issue, it would be greatly appreciated as I have been working on this issue for the past week.

Comment: It happed to me also a year ago when i was installing windows 7 using unetbootin and i also ran into the same link given above while searching for solution and used the Windows 7 USB/DVD Download tool and it worked,did you use it??

Comment: In the article you linked there are 5 causes of this error, all having something to do with faulty DVD or DVD-drive, and errors reading files. One of them is corrupted installation files.

Comment: @Kitet I know. I read the article I linked..

Comment: @Franco I will try to use that. I just need to get to a Windows machine which that will happen later. Thanks for the tip.